# How to use Hebrew or Arabic in v-text-field

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js, vuetify.js

I am using veutify and everything is working great but my label is gibberish when I am using Hebrew, how can I solve that?
This is my code  :

```
 <v-text-field v-model="phone_number" class="ma-8" :rules="[rules.required,rules.digits, rules.counter]" label="מספר פלאפון" counter="true" maxlength="10"></v-text-field>
```

I use :

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.x/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.js"></script>
```

Comment: Are your rtl text settings right? Does other text work fine?

Comment: You could maybe convert the label text to rtl and then call that function in the to return that label.

Comment: I use this  :new Vue({
            el: '#app',
            vuetify: new Vuetify({
                rtl: true,
            }),

Comment: @mahatmanich thanks, I am new to vuetify and need to edit the current code, do you have an example I'm not sure what to change. All text is in gibberish.

Comment: sorry I never used vuetify but from what you are writing, rtl is not applied properly ...

Comment: Sounds like an encoding issue. Shouldn't be an issue today when everything is UTF-8, but worth a check. Do you have a `<meta charset="utf-8">` element in your page's `head` section?

Comment: @TsahiAsher thank you!! please write it as an answer and  I'll mark it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like an encoding issue. Make sure you have `<meta charset="utf-8">` element in your page's `head` section.